# bringing focus to the parent window from a child window launched via showmodaldialog

Tags: javascript, html, focus, showmodaldialog

I have a scenario like this.

Window 1->opens->modal popup->opens-> window 2.

Modal popup is launched using showmodaldialog method from window 1. From the modal popup a normal window (window 2) is launched using "window.open" method. On launching the window 2, the modal popup is closed using `self.close()` in the popup window's javascript.

Now the windows open are window 1 & window 2. I want to transfer the focus of the window 1 from window 2. is there anyway this can be done?

I have removed other programming code due to security restrictions at the workplace. However, given below is the gist of the code for the scenario I have explained above. Please let me know if there is anything that can be done to solve this problem?

Following is my code:

- Parent Window (window 1):

  ```
  <html>
   <head><title> Parent Window <title>
    <script> 
        function show_popup(){ 
        base_win=window; 
        var win1=window.showModalDialog("Child_Window 1.html",base_win,"dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:500px;dialogLeft:300");
         } 
     </script> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        This is the parent Window 
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="click this" onclick="javascript:show_popup();">
    </body> 
  </html>
  ```
- Modal Popup Window:

  ```
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>Child Window 1</title>
     <script> 
           function show_window(){ 
           var win1=window.open("Child_Window 2.html","");
           self.close();
            }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        This is the Child Window 1 
         <br>
         <br>
         <input type="button" id="but1" value="click this" onclick="javascript:show_window();">
     </body>
   </html>
  ```
- Child Window (window 2):

  ```
  <html>
    <head>
       <title>Child Window 2</title>
        <script> 
            function goto_parent(){
             var w = window.opener; 
             window.opener = self; 
             w.focus(); 
             } 
         </script> 
       </head> 
       <body> 
           This is the child Window 
            <input type="button" id="but1" value="parent window" onclick="javascript:goto_parent();">
       </body>
   </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window 1 will not be functional until the ModalDialog is not closed. 
Hence, call the instance of the 3rd window immediately after the following code in your base window -

```
 var win1=window.showModalDialog("Child_Window 1.html",base_win,"dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:500px;dialogLeft:300");
```

Once the ModalDialog is closed, base window will call for the focus of your desirable window.